# Force preload all images to browser

Tags: javascript, browser, preload

i have some little games on js. While gaming, some images load with timeout. How can i force preload all images by browser of client on start?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having individual images it's better and more performant to create a single sprite sheet. With a sprite sheet you basically load one image and use it as the background image for your sprites / actors. You then show the correct image with the CSS `background-position` settings.

[More info on using sprite sheets](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Example of a spritesheet

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This method is known to me. But i cant use it.